# WebDriverException: Message: quit

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have the following set up:

```
Linux
Python 2.7.6
Mozilla Firefox 52.2.0
geckodriver 0.18.0
selenium Version: 3.4.3
```

I'm running a simple python script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)  # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'image/png')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("file:////home/temp-plot.html")
export_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-title='Download plot as a png']")
export_button.click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

But when I reach the `driver.quit()`, I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversor.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver.quit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 181, in quit
    RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 551, in quit
    self.execute(Command.QUIT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: quit
```

If I run `driver.close()` instead of `driver.quit()`, I have no error message, but in other hand, I find the geckodriver process is not killed, which is a problem for me.

```
root     14572     1  0 11:56 pts/0    00:00:00 geckodriver --port 39203
```

How can I fix this exception error? Or what do you suggest me to do?

Thanks

Comment: how about calling `webdriver.quit()` after `webdriver.close()`

Comment: @GaurangShah the same behaviour occurs: I have the exception and the process is not killed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me:

```
driver.close()
```

instead of:

```
driver.quit()
```

I'm on python3, selenium 3.4.3

Comment: Yes, but like I said, if you do this, the geckodriver process still remains running. Which means the port remains open.

Answer (score -1):

I don't why geckodriver does this, but exception catch does the job on our project:

```
try:
    self.driver.quit()
except WebDriverException:
    pass
```

Browser and gecko driver are closed and no useless errors are reported.